# code for card on material-ui's front page

Tags: material-ui

`material-ui` has a very nice looking set of cards on its front page.  I couldn't figure out how to achieve the same aestetic using the standard `card` examples.  Could somebody please provide a code/template for achieving that.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example of how you can achieve this using toolbars and the card component

https://jsfiddle.net/davidebarros/sd1g9fza/2/

render() {

```
return (
  <div style={{width: '50%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
     <Card>
      <Toolbar style={{"justify-content": "center"}}>
         <ToolbarTitle  text="Material UI" />
      </Toolbar>
      <CardMedia><img src="http://www.material-ui.com/images/get-started.svg" alt=""/></CardMedia>
     </Card>
  </div>
);
```

}